# How can I convert images taken for a panorama as a hexagonal prism into an equirectangular image?

Tags: panorama, 360-panorama, pano-projections

We have a client who wants us to make a panorama for them using some photos a previous supplier took.

The images in question seem to be a type of panorama I've never seen before:

- The files we received consist of eight portrait, rectangular images.
- The files seem to piece together to make a hexagonal prism - six around, one up, one down - with the top and bottom faces overlapping.
- Each image is 2848 x 4288px.

Their original tour was made in Pano2VR, but Pano2VR won't accept the files. As there's no overlap between the six horizontal images, we can't stitch them.

Has anyone ever encountered this type of panorama before? What's the best way to convert these files into an equirectangular image?

Comment: Can't make a panorama with any software if there is no overlap at all. It just can't be done. If there is even a little overlap, then there still is some hope left.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto There's no overlap at all, sadly, it's pixel perfect. I'm hoping that whatever converted it into this hexagonal prism shape could convert it back - you can do the same for panoramas that have been converted into cube faces.

Comment: So a manual alignment might be possible in Photoshop or suchlike? Any chance that you'd edit the question to include a sample picture? You have now the needed reputation to put images in.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto I'd like to include the example images, sadly there's some copyright issues with the original supplier so I'm not able to share. I realise that makes identifying much harder.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to add images into Hugin and calculate) coordinates of images (or move them in OpenGl preview by hand), six faces will differ Yaw (0,60,120,180,240,300), top and bottom will have Pitch  +90 and -90 , and then you must figure right projection (switch objectives) and hfov  to  "fill the frame". Then you can render it.

I have successfully used this method to convert six cube faces into equirectangular panorama.

Comment: Nice. I'll try this later to convert between projections.

Answer (score 2):

I really wish you could post at least a downgraded, blurred version of your images.

If I understand you correctly, you could use a 3D modeling tool, such as Blender to texture up a simple hexagonal prism mesh that matches your images. Then using a properly aligned camera you could create the overlap images, and then you could use a stitching program.

Comment: Clever idea. Kerkythea (Kerkythea.net) can export directly a spherical projection, which could be converted directly to cubic projection.